# Access modification Apple Combine

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to think in terms of API Design because ultimately I want to ship code to myself or others.

Let's make some assumptions in order to get a succinct scenario. We will assume I have some Code that authenticates with my server and returns a user object. Defined simply like this:

```swift
public struct User: Codable {
    public let id: UUID
    public let email: String
    public let name: String
}
```

I'm writing this code as an SDK I would ship to myself or a third party where all the guts of AUTH are handled. Using Apples new Combine framework I might expose a publisher for the consumer of my SDK like this.

```swift
public enum CurrentUserError: Error {
    case loggedOut
    case sessionExpired
}

public struct MyAuthFrameworkPublishers {
    static let currentUser: CurrentValueSubject<User?, CurrentUserError> = CurrentValueSubject<User?, CurrentUserError>(nil)
}
```

Now, my private auth could accomplish it's task and retrieve a user then publish that to anything outside the SDK that it listening like so:

```swift
class AuthController {
    func authenticate() {
        ///Get authenticated user.
        let user = User.init(id: UUID(), email: "some@some.com", name: "some")
        MyAuthFrameworkPublishers.currentUser.send(user)
    }
}
let authController = AuthController.init()
authController.authenticate()
```

Is there a way to keep or stop the user of this SDK from sending it's own `User` object to the publisher? Like a private or access controller `.send()` function in combine?

Comment: I don't really see this as a somewhere you should use an extension.  `currentUser` should be a property of your own framework

Comment: The consumer of the framework might want to display user details in a way they see fit. This framework would just be managing the AUTH. Regardless, do you know of a way to control who can send to a publisher?

Comment: To answer your second question, no, but the only thing that can be published by your publisher is your `User`.  The type is bound based on context and the context of `User` in your extension is your `User`, not any arbitrary class called User.  I still don't see why your user publisher should be part of the `Publisher` object.  It is part of your framework.  Where the publisher lives doesn't affect how the consumer uses the publisher, merely how they refer to it.  "MyFramework.currentUser` is much clearer than `Publisher.currentUser`

Comment: Thanks, Paulw11. I have kind of wondered the best way to "namespace" publishers. Maybe my own static struct? I edited the question with your suggestion.

Comment: First, I am not really sure why a consumer would publish their own `User` or why it would matter if they did, but you can probably manage this simply by protecting the `User` initialiser.  If you can't make an instance of `User` outside your framework then only your framework can publish it.

Comment: Paulw11, Yeah, I though the same thing. I guess my example starts to break down a little here. There is a possibility my internal framework would make a subscription to that publisher to react too changes. Like to cache to disk or do logging. Either way you are right. A consumer of my framework here would not be able to construct a User object. However, they could still mess with the publisher by sending completions.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to use `CurrentUserError` as your `Failure` type? Sending a failure ends any subscriptions to the subject and fails new ones immediately. If the session expires, don't you want to let the user log in again? That would require publishing another `User?` output, which you cannot do if you have published a failure.

Instead, use `Result<User?, CurrentUserError>` as your `Output` type, and `Never` as your `Failure` type.

Now, on to your question. In general, the way to prevent the user from calling `send` is to vend an `AnyPublisher` instead of a `Subject`:

```
public class AuthController {

    public let currentUser: AnyPublisher<Result<User?, AuthenticationError>, Never>

    public func authenticate() {
        let user: User = ...
        subject.send(user)
    }

    public init() {
        currentUser = subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    private let subject = CurrentValueSubject<Result<User?, AuthenticationError>, Never>(nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! Erasing to AnyPublisher is a great idea. I like that you are publishing a publisher. I'm still struggling to make combine concepts my default thought process. I also like how you separate the public and private publishers, brilliant. Any thoughts on making the public publisher more accessible with out having to pass a reference around? Like, if my AppDelegate constructed the AuthController but a user profile page deep in the app needed it could I just make the public publisher static? Or if some other networking controller needed a reference in the app background?